# Flutter: Google Map detect camera is moving / not moving state

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a return whether the camera is moving or not moving. Below code is the one provided by the plugin google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+8. It is just a normal voidcallback function without return any value. Is it possible to get the is moving state or not moving state?

```
void Function() onCameraMoveStarted
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about is moving state, but you can detect if the camera is idle / stopped moving by implementing the `onCameraIdle` method. I'm using `version 2.1.1`. There are other helpful methods like `onCameraMove` which gives you the current camera position.